# How to increase hand speed in boxing

Tags: technique, boxing, speed

**Goal:**

I am looking to use the form and strength that I have built in boxing and start towards hand speed.

**Problem:**

I have a lot of power, the problem is my hand speed is suffering because of the amount of resistance/compound training I have been doing over the years.

**Question:**

What are the most effective methods to increase a boxers hand speed given my problem and my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Improving hand speed means improving Speed strength, you can do that by doing

- plyometrics
- punching with bands
- throwing medicine balls or dumbbells
- shot putting

But, you should also pay attention on the execution of your punching technique.
Buy that i mean you should "throw" your hands through the opponent, initiated or catapulted from the legs via the shoulder, and during this motion you should be as relaxed as possible. When you tense up, you are becoming slower.
The only thing that needs to be tight is your fist and upon impact you should
tense up.

You can use a small exercise and try to punch through a peace of paper that is attached to a rope or something from the ceiling. if you can rip the paper in half that would be a confirmation of a solid punch. In short, the drill is useful. The piece of paper isn't what causes improvements however. It is the fact that you are consciously trying to hit the paper with a snap (ie. as fast as you can). The best way to become fast is by training fast. This simple logic is seen with the drill.

Comment: Thanks again mitro! By the way your tire idea is great.. I ended up using the tire on the back of my jeeps. Didn't need to cut it in half but I can practice punches to the body.

Answer (score 0):

I went into boxing from a jujitsu-style art and thought I had a fast punch until my coach put me on the floor to ceiling ball and I got yet another lesson in humility. My punch speed went up like crazy and people I used to spar with commented on it. Wonderful piece of kit.